# How to open NFS log

Tags: mount, nfs, omnios

I'm using Omnios (Unix) and i want to log everything about nfs.

I have some VM on my NFS share and sometimes connection brokes 3-5 second.
I can not find a reason for that on dmesg or syslog.
I can watch SMB logs from "dmesg" but nfs logs not writing there.

I think i need to open my logs someway.
Any help works. Ty.

Answer (score 0):

On "linux" before `journald` was `syslog` / `syslog-ng` which was setup in `/etc/syslog.conf` by setting the **facility**.**severity** filter to a /var/log/filepath. You could have that on unix...

Answer (score 0):

OmniOs is `solaris` not `linux`

`nfs` logging needs to be set in the `share` command:

`share -F nfs -ro,log=global /export/ftp`

source: [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36825/rfsadmin-101.html)